# Как обработать ссылку?

Tags: javascript

У нас ссылка генерируется в таком формате site.com/&message=Test+пример+текста

Использую JS.
Так вот, как сделать что бы когда мы будем парсить данные из ссылки, как нам выводить текст что бы вместо "+" были пробелы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно регуляркой, предварительно создав свою функцию:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), 'g'), replacement);
};

// нужно для экранирования специальных символов перед срезом
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"); // $& значит: все совпадения
}
```

тогда:

`"Test+пример+текста".replaceAll('+', ' ')`

---

Или с помощью `split` и `join`

`split` - разбивает объект String на массив строк путём разделения строки указанной подстрокой.
Синтаксис: `str.split([separator[, limit]])`. Где `separator` - необязательный параметр. Указывает символы, используемые в качестве разделителя внутри строки. 
Параметр `separator` может быть как строкой, так и регулярным выражением.

`join` - объединяет все элементы массива в строку. 
Синтаксис: `str = arr.join([separator = ','])`, где `separator` -
необязательный параметр. Определяется строку, разделяющую элементы массива. Разделитель приводится к строке в случае необходимости. Если он опущен, элементы массива разделяются запятой.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Аналогично: `"Test+пример+текста".replaceAll('+', ' ')`

Comment: split + join затратнее чем регулярка. так что я бы не стал рекомендовать в данном случае, т.к. не известно на сколько будет разбиваться частей строка.

Comment: @Pleshevskiy это просто один из вариантов. У меня нет рекомендаций)) и регулярка специально первой идет.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!